# How to get the sub claim in TokenIssuedSuccessEvent and UserLoginSuccessEvent

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I am implementing an `IEventSink` for `TokenIssuedSuccessEvent` and `UserLoginSuccessEvent`.

I can use the `TokenIssuedSuccessEvent.SubjectId` to get the subject id but I would also like to get the issuer. Unfortunately, the `sub` claim itself is not exposed in the event.

When digging through the IdentityServer code I can see that the `SubjectId` does come from a `ClaimsPrincipal` on the line `SubjectId = response.Request.Subject.GetSubjectId();`.

I was thinking I might be able to get the current claims principal from the `HttpContext` using `HttpContext.User.Claims` in my `IEventSink` but these claims are empty so I'm guessing it is not set yet.

When looking at the IdentityServer logs I can see the `DefaultClaimsService` working with the claims.

```
2019-09-02 21:34:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService
Getting claims for access token for client: SomeClientId

TokenIssuedSuccessEvent was received in event sink
TokenIssuedSuccessEvent was received in event sink

[2019-09-02 21:34:12 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
Token request success.
```

How can I get the claims, or at least the `sub` claim for these two events?

Comment: it looks, it is currently in the state of rethinking: see [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3199) github issue and the linked ones

Comment: Yes, sorry. Should have linked that as well. Hoping to get away without creating custom events.